# Attach file with spaces in the name

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

I can't attach files with spaces in the name, but when have no space 
is successfully attached, i'm using codeigniter for this, 
uploading the file to the server before attach it, i use the helper Path for get the routes to my file.

```
function upload_file() {

    //$this->load->helper('path');
    //$path = set_realpath('./uploads/');

    //upload file

    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = '*';
    $config['max_filename'] = '255';
    $config['encrypt_name'] = FALSE;
    $config['max_size'] = '50000';
    $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if (isset($_FILES['file']['name'])) {
        if (0 < $_FILES['file']['error']) {
            echo 'Error durante la carga' . $_FILES['file']['error'];
        } else {
            if (file_exists('./uploads/' . $_FILES['file']['name'])) {
                echo 'Nombre de archivo ya existe : uploads/' . $_FILES['file']['name'];
            } else {
                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                if (!$this->upload->do_upload('file')) {
                    echo $this->upload->display_errors();
                } else {
                    echo 'Archivo cargado! : ./uploads/' . $_FILES['file']['name'];
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Porfavor selecciona un archivo';
    }
}
```

Part of sendMail function:

```
 $archivo = $_FILES['file']['name'];
 $path = set_realpath('./uploads/');
 $adjunto = $path.$archivo;
 $this->email->attach($adjunto);
```

Part of the view and JS

```
<input type="file" id="file" name="file" />

$(document).ready(function (e) {
$('#file').on('change', function () {
  var file_data = $('#file').prop('files')[0];
  var form_data = new FormData();
  form_data.append('file', file_data);
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://mail.mayordomus.cl/Cpersona/upload_file', 
    dataType: 'text', 
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: form_data,
    type: 'post',
    success: function (response) {
        $('#msg').html(response); 
    },
    error: function (response) {
        $('#msg').html(response);
    }
  });
});
```

});

Comment: What is the requirement? Are you trying to adjust the file name at client or server?

Comment: did you try `utf8_encode`

Comment: Try %20 as the escape character.

Comment: @guest271314 i'm trying to adjust the client file name, because the server file name is created replacing the spaces with underscores.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove space characters from file name at client side using `File` constructor

```js
let files = [new File([1], "file name.txt"), new File([2], "file name1.txt")];

let fd = new FormData();

for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  console.log(`Original file name: ${files[i].name}`); 
  let filename = files[i].name.replace(/\s/g, "-");
  let file = new File([files[i].slice()], filename);
  fd.append("files-" + i, file);
}

for (let [, prop] of fd) {
  console.log(`FormData file name:${prop.name}`);
}
```